# perl/sql server query "re-ordered"

Tags: sql-server, perl, reorderlist

Sorry for asking this question I am sure this was already answered somewhere else but I don't even know what keywords or how to explain it properly...
So... I have this perl code that connects to sql server..

```
my $user = '';
my $pass = '.';
my $connection = "dbi:Sybase:server=;database=Adventure";
my $dbh_SQL = DBI->connect($connection, $user, $pass) or die 'Cannot connect';
my $query_cust_main = "
SELECT BusinessEntityID,
       Title,
       FirstName,
       LastName,
       Suffix,
       JobTitle

FROM HumanResources.vEmployee
order by JobTitle";

my $query_cust_sth = $dbh_SQL->prepare($query_cust_main);
$query_cust_sth->execute();
my $all_cust = $dbh_SQL->selectall_arrayref($query_cust_main, {Slice => {}});

foreach my $data (@$all_cust){
print $data->{BusinessEntityID}." ".$data->{FirstName}." ".$data->{LastName}." ".$data->{JobTitle}."\n";
}
```

This code prints:
12 Thierry D'Hers Tool Designer
13 Janice Galvin Tool Designer
2 Terri Duffy Vice President of Engineering
25 James Hamilton Vice President of Production
273 Brian Welcker Vice President of Sales

Now, what i want to do...somehow is to re-order the results as this:

**Vice President of Production**

25 James Hamilton

273 Brian Welcker

**Tool Designer**

13 Janice Galvin

12 Thierry D'Hers

As in

**JobTitle**

BusinessEntityID FirstName LastName ...

Is is possible to obtain this re order only in perl? without using/altering the query?

Thank you,
R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the query is returning the data sorted by job title, all you have to do is keep track of what the previous job title was and when it is different to the current one, print out a new job title header like this code snippet demonstrates.

```
my $last_job_title;
foreach my $data (@$all_cust) {
    if($last_job_title ne $data->{JobTitle}) {
        $last_job_title = $data->{JobTitle};
        print $data->{JobTitle},"\n";
    }
    print $data->{BusinessEntityID}." ".$data->{FirstName}." ".$data->{LastName}."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure someone could give you a cool nested SQL command to do this, but I was a Perl programming before a SQL programmer.  So, if you don't have to worry about SQL performance, you should query the DB for all the different Job Titles (unless you already know them), and then loop through the Titles (`foreach my $title (@jobTitles)`), printing out the title and then all the records that match that title (`WHERE JobTitle=$title` kind of thing).